target is configured multiple time's
When I type
mbr@MBR:~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy main'

I get
Repository: 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description: Archive for codename: jammy components: main More info:
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ Adding repository. Press
[ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel. Found existing deb entry in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Hit:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease Hit:2
https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease              
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu mantic InRelease       
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu
jammy InRelease                                                       
Hit:6 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease             
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease      
Hit:8 https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/repositories/debian
universal InRelease Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
jammy-backports InRelease Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
jammy-security InRelease Reading package lists... Done W: Target
ackages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple
times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times
in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target DEP-11
(main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target DEP-11
(main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple
times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times
in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured
multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target CNF
(main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target CNF
(main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
(main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple
times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times
in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target DEP-11
(main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target DEP-11
(main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple
times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times
in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured
multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target CNF
(main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target CNF
(main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1

aptsources-cleanup.pyz didn't help.

You've marked your pastes as quoted text (ie. paragraphs of text) and not as {code]; which has resulted in your question being somewhat hard to read.  Please use {code} tags (not quoted  text.prose).

Does this answer your question? How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?

You have apparently already add'ed the winehq repository earlier. No need to keep doing that.
In the directory /etc/apt/sources.list you have two files containing same definitions, archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1 and winehq-jammy.sources:1
Verify the content of these two files and remove doublets ... you probably should remove the file called archive_uri... and keep all winehq definitions in the other one.
Make a backup before you change anything - you can just copy the two files to your home-dir.
Then run sudo apt update
